# How to Stop Jquery Popup from loading again when user again click on HomePage?

Tags: jquery, jsp, popup

I am using REVEAL Overlay Popup . It display a popup whenever `HOME page(index.jsp)` loads using :-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#myModal').reveal();
});
```

Problem is if user again click on HOME `( index.jsp)` popup again loads. Please help.

How do I prevent popup to load again if user again click on Home Page?

Comment: You can use cookies. On each load, check if cookie present, if not add the cookie and show popup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first time you showed the popup, you should store a value indicating that it is shown in a cookie. just check the cookie and then show popup:

```
 $(document).ready(
function() { 
if(!cookieexists){
$('#myModal').reveal(); 
//add the cookie
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am posting the code that i am using to store Cookies Using javascript on page LOAD to solve problem like i was facing. Thank for prompt reply from  Ashkan Mobayen Khiabani and P5Coder

```
 <script>

                $(document).ready( function(){
                if(!document.cookie)
                {
                   $('#myModal').reveal(); 
                   document.cookie="detected=yes";
                }
                });

            </script>
```